# How to reduce function call count for a function that is run after animation completion with Cytoscape

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have an animation on a collection of nodes. However, after completion of the animation I want it to call a function just once, but the function is apparently called as many times as there are nodes in the collection. Is there a way to stop this? I just want it to run once. Fairly new to Javascript, appreciate any help.

```
  collection.animate({
    style: {
      'line-color': 'red',
      'target-arrow-color': 'red',
      'border-width': 20,
      'border-color': 'red'
    }
  }, {
    'duration': 3000,
    'complete': () => "hello world";
  });
```

Prints 9x "hello world" since my collection of nodes and edges is of length 9 (subbranch of nodes & edges in a directed graph)

[image: https://i.imgur.com/K3yyMv7.gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy. Just put a boolean variable to check if is already executed.

```
let isExecuted = false;

collection.animate({
  style: {
    'line-color': 'red',
    'target-arrow-color': 'red',
    'border-width': 20,
    'border-color': 'red'
  }
}, {
  'duration': 3000,
  'complete': () => {
    if (isExecuted) {
      return;
    }
    console.log("hello world");
    isExecuted = true;
  };
});
```